# Are Scala and Scala.js the same?

Tags: scala, scala.js

I don't know Scala yet. I saw Scala and Scala.js. So, are they same or are they not? And can we use Scala.js in Node.js (like everything else with "js" in the name)?

Comment: Was there something about the Scala.js home page that you had a specific question about? As it is, your question is too broad to answer.

Comment: No, they are not the same. Scala is a programming language, Scala.js is an implementation of that language. Just like HTML is a language and Chrome is an implementation, or ECMAScript is a language and V8, Chakra, SpiderMonkey, etc. are implementations. Nobody would say that ECMAScript and V8 are the same.

Answer (score 6):

Scala is a language that compiles to Java bytecode and runs on the Java Virtual Machine, Scala.js has the same syntax as Scala and libraries to help write web apps, but compiles to Javascript so it can run in a browser. You cannot write Scala.js code in a Node.js app, because the Node.js compiler will not know what it is, it has to be its own app built and managed by Scala's simple-build-tool (sbt). Node.js is its own framework that expects javascript code

Comment: You can compile Scala.js code to JS code that does work in Node.js, though. (Just making that clear for passers-by; your answer is correct as is, but might be misunderstood.)

Comment: Also note that Scala.js does not only have the same syntax as Scala, it also has the same *semantics*. I.e. the same (vanilla) Scala code will do the same thing on JVM and JS.

Comment: "Scala is a language that compiles to Java bytecode and runs on the Java Virtual Machine" – No, it is not. Scala is a language. Languages don't compile to anything. Compilers compile. I think you are confusing the Scala language with the Scala compiler. Scala is a language. The Scala-JVM compiler, Scala.js, Scala-native, and the discontinued Scala.NET are just different implementations of that language.